# Using delete operator in a pointer in vector

Tags: c++, memory-management, syntax-error

I have the following vector:

```
std::vector<xml::Node *> *children;
```

In my destructor I need to explicitly call `delete` on the elements pointed to by `Node *` elements in the children. So I do the following:

```
std::cout << "xml::Element destructor" << std::endl;
if(children != NULL) {
    if(n_children() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n_children(); i++) {
            delete children[i];
        }
    }
    delete children;
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
oops.cpp: In destructor ‘virtual xml::Element::~Element()’:
oops.cpp:277:42: error: type ‘class std::vector<xml::Node*>’ argument given to ‘delete’, expected pointer
```

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
delete children[i];
```

should be

```
delete (*children)[i];
```

because `children` is a pointer.

Well, that is the problem with your code at syntactical level, though I feel that there would still be problem at design level even after you fix the above syntax. Why  have you declared `children` as pointer? Why not just this:

```
std::vector<xml::Node*> children; //non-pointer now
```

Do you have any *solid* reason why you didn't opt for this?

Declaring a container as pointer in most cases defies its very purpose as far as memory management is concerned. You use container because you don't want to handle memory-management yourself. Instead you want the container itself to take that burden. The container releases all the resources automatically when it goes out of scope. But if you declare a container as pointer, then you're taking the burden to delete the container. If you miss to do that, then the container will never release the resources which it has acquired, and there will be memory leak.